# How to update internal changelog topic partitions when a source topic partition count is updated?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have an application in which I'm using a Kstream-Kstream join and Ktream-Ktable join.
I have updated the input source topic partition count from 4 to 16 and the application stopped with below error.

`Could not create internal topics: Existing internal topic application-test-processor-KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000009-store-changelog has invalid partitions. Expected: 16 Actual: 4. Use 'kafka.tools.StreamsResetter' tool to clean up invalid topics before processing. Retry #3`

How to update internal changelog topic partition count when a source topic partition count is updated ?

Note: We are using kafka version: 0.10.2.1

I looked at the application resetter tool from this link: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html
but it doesn't say how to update the changelog partition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Using the reset tool is actually recommended.

The state of your application is sharded based on the number of input partitions. This was originally 4. Thus, changing it to 16 broke the application. If you would manually add partitions to the changelog topic (what would be possible and resolve the exception, but not really fix the issue), state would not be redistributed and thus would be corrupted.

If you use the reset tool, you delete all state and let your application reprocess all input data from scratch. This allows Kafka Streams to recreate the state correctly (now with 16 shards).

Comment: Thanks Matt.
I don't want to reprocess the messages. Is it possible to delete only the internal topics using the application reset tool and then restart the application so that the internal topics are recreated ?

Comment: That is possible -- you also need to delete local state via `KafkaStreams#cleanup()` or manually -- otherwise, you would not start with an empty state.

Comment: Hi @MatthiasJ.Sax if your changelog has a higher retention policy than the original topic, how are you supposed to rebuild your state? You will have to replay the events on the original topic, won't you?

Comment: Changelog topics don't have a retention time, but use log compaction. -- And yes, you can only reprocess what is still available in your input topics. This means, if your state contains data that cannot be recomputed because input data is missing, you would loose part of your state.